# Get selected text in Format Area

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, javascript, angularjs

I want to get selected text in RTF using Anguilla. I cannot get it using pure JS because it is in an iframe. There is an option to use `editor.getSelectedHTMLElement()` to get selected HTML element, but that is not what I want. I want to get a pure text that user selected. I cannot find anything similar in Anguilla. Is there something there that I can use?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found out in [this blog](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/AnguillaSnippets) that simple `.toString()` over

```
>$display.getView().properties.activeEditor.getSelectedHTMLElement().toString()
```

will return the text.